# Android TextView next to ImageView set text programmatically causing a null when referencing

Tags: java, android, android-layout, tabview

Hey all I am trying to figure out how to put text into a **TextView** that's beside a **ImageView** so that I can label each image as this section of code does:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
    GlobalCls.hideSystemUI(getWindow());
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GlobalCls._loadGlobalCls(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.this);
    GlobalCls.database = openOrCreateDatabase(GlobalCls.dbName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    GlobalCls.createSQLTbl();

    startLoading();
}

private void startLoading() {
  tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.mTabLayout);
  viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
  //adapter setup
  pagerAdapter = new com.telluridetainment.PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
  pagerAdapter.addFragment(new com.telluridetainment.FragMovies(), "Movies");
  pagerAdapter.addFragment(new com.telluridetainment.FragShows(), "Shows");
  pagerAdapter.addFragment(new com.telluridetainment.FragMusic(), "Music");
  pagerAdapter.addFragment(new com.telluridetainment.FragAndroid(), "Android")
  pagerAdapter.addFragment(new com.telluridetainment.FragGame2(), "game1");
  pagerAdapter.addFragment(new com.telluridetainment.FragGame1(), "game2");

  if (GlobalCls.theUser.equals("j")) {
    pagerAdapter.addFragment(new com.telluridetainment.FragUser(), "j");
  } else {
    pagerAdapter.addFragment(new com.telluridetainment.FragUser(), "t");
  }

  viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(7);
  viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
  tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

  for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
    //TextView t = findViewById(R.id.tabText);

    switch (i) {
    case 0:
      if (tab != null) {
        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.movies);
        //t.setText("Movies");
      }
      break;
    case 1:
      if (tab != null) {
        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.shows);
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      if (tab != null) {
        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.music);
      }
      break;
    case 3:
      if (tab != null) {
        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.android);
      }
      break;
    case 4:
      if (tab != null) {
        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.game1);
      }
      break;
    case 5:
      if (tab != null) {
        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.game2);
      }
      break;
    case 6:
      if (tab != null) {
        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.j);
      }
      break;
    }

    if (tab != null) tab.setCustomView(R.layout.my_custom_tab);
  }
}
```

And the XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabText"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabText"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="hi"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
        android:maxHeight="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The code works just fine. It places the image(s) where I need them with the text (currently only static text) beside it.

[image]

However, when I try the code

```
t.setText("Movies");
```

I know it finds the TextView because it has it's number when I hover over it:

[image]

But like I said above once it gets to setting the text it's 'null':

[image]

Not sure what it is I'm doing incorrectly to cause it to be `null`?

**UPDATE 1**

Here is the error log that was requested:

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tridetainment, PID: 15100
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tridetainment/com.tridetainment.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.tridetainment.MainActivity.lambda$startLoading$3$com-tridetainment-MainActivity(MainActivity.java:213)
        at com.tridetainment.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:6904)
        at com.tridetainment.MainActivity.startLoading(MainActivity.java:178)
        at com.tridetainment.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:310)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15100 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:41902', transport: 'socket'
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have added more code to the above to show the relationship(s).

**UPDATE 3**

Updated the code to the full call.

**UPDATE 4**

This is the **main_activty** XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_x="10dp"
    android:layout_y="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/mainPage"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.tridetainment.noTabSwiping
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:tag="VP"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mTabLayout"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/mTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="#F44336"
        android:tag="TL"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTabText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="10dp"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/grey"
        app:tabInlineLabel="true"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mTabLayout"
        android:layout_x="10dp"
        android:layout_y="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gui_tabshadow"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/viewPager" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#122AFF"
        android:tag="VF"
        android:visibility="invisible">

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can repost with logs?

Comment: @Elango I posted the error log in my OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should be the problem then, you did not set the custom view for your tab layout and so it is giving the null pointer exception. This code should now work fine

```
  viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(7);
  viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
  tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
    if (tab != null) tab.setCustomView(R.layout.my_custom_tab);
    TextView t = findViewById(R.id.tabText);
    // if it still gives error replace the above referencing with
    //  TextView t = (TextView)tab.view.findViewById(R.id.tabText);
  switch (i) {
    case 0:
      if (tab != null) {
        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.movies);
        t.setText("Movies");
      }
      break;
    case 1:
      if (tab != null) {
        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.shows);
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      if (tab != null) {
        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.music);
      }
      break;
    case 3:
      if (tab != null) {
        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.android);
      }
      break;
    case 4:
      if (tab != null) {
        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.game1);
      }
      break;
    case 5:
      if (tab != null) {
        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.game2);
      }
      break;
    case 6:
      if (tab != null) {
        tab.setIcon(R.drawable.j);
      }
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i provided the full amount of code.

Comment: sorry my bad i have updated my answer.

Comment: Mind showing me an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: I edited my answer to help you understand better. Lmk if you don't understand something

Comment: Thanks for the visual. However, it seems to still have an error on the t.setText()    `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tridetainment/com.tridetainment.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Comment: try adding context inside relative layout as ```tools:context =".MainActivity"```

Comment: The text is within the R.layout.my_custom_tab. So that is being placed onto the activity_main fragment. Check my Update 4 in my OP.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if your issue gets resolved. This will also help others :)

Comment: Boom. Finally worked. Much appreciated Arsh!

Comment: For the record the second type needed to be used or it would just stay on the first text only no matter how much you looped. `TextView t = (TextView)tab.view.findViewById(R.id.tabText);`

Answer (score 1):

findviewbyid is returning null probably because you're not calling it on the parent of the view you are looking for. if tab is the parent of the textview then replace findViewById(R.id.tabText) with tab.view.findViewById(R.id.tabText).

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
     TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
     TextView t = (TextView)tab.view.findViewById(R.id.tabText);
```

Comment: That throws an error of `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tridetainment/com.tridetainment.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: I have also added to my code in the OP to show more of the relationships between everything.

Comment: @StealthRT i updated the answer. this should work.

Comment: Sadly it still a `null` value.